# Calendar time portfolio construction

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio, portfolio-selection

I am writing my master's thesis about analyst star-rankings and whether their recommendations have investment value. For these purposes I am trying to construct calendar time portfolios as it was made in previous research. I would like to ask whether I am on the right way with my methodology. Many thanks beforehand!
**The literature gives this kind of formula**
[image: :]

Source: Yuri Kucheev, *The Value of Ranked Analysts' Recommendations*, 2017 [Link](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1088235/FULLTEXT01.pdf)

**I am trying to repeat it by doing this kind of operation in excel. I am calculating the cumulative returns, I am also calculating the total cumulative return for the last day of investment. And I repeat it for every single company in my portfolio**  [image]

Comment: have you ever found an answer to this? I am currently facing the same problem and would appreciate any guidance you can provide.